# How to use Single_Source_Shortest_Path in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-databases

## Background

I’ve created a graph database using the **Networkx** package for about 80,000 nodes and 230,000 edges. Each node in the database represents register and the edge represents the dependencies between the registers. The goal of the analysis is to determine the impact of removing a subset of nodes with respect to the dependencies for a defined degree cutoff (current set to 3).

My approach has been to populate the graph database i.e. The 80k nodes and 230k edges (see **g** in the below code), then iterate through the subset of nodes which represent a list of registered designated for removal (see **all_registered_to_be_removed**) using the **single_source_shortest_path()** method. The method then generates lists of paths detailing all of the effected dependandants (see **all_dependant_paths**) . This list is used to populate a new graph database (see **impact_graph**).

## Problem

From what I can tell, this approach works for a handful of paths, but quickly falls apart. As it generates an error, quite often the error is triggered for a different node. Can anyone suggest a different approach?

```
impact_graph = nx.Graph()
for register in all_registered_to_be_removed:
    all_dependant_paths = nx.single_source_shortest_path(g, source=register, cutoff=3)
    impact_graph.add_path(all_dependant_paths)
```

## stack trace of error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-206-4291f9128bde> in <module>()
      1 impact_graph = nx.Graph()
      2 for tag in all_registered_to_be_removed:
----> 3     all_dependant_paths = nx.single_source_shortest_path(g, source=tag, cutoff=3)
      4     impact_graph.add_path(all_dependant_paths)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/unweighted.pyc in single_source_shortest_path(G, source, cutoff)
    252         nextlevel={}
    253         for v in thislevel:
--> 254             for w in G[v]:
    255                 if w not in paths:
    256                     paths[w]=paths[v]+[w]

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/networkx/classes/graph.pyc in __getitem__(self, n)
    319         {1: {}}
    320         """
--> 321         return self.adj[n]
    322 
    323
```

Comment: The source "tag" is probably not in the graph "g".